# Saving asset title in frontend form

Tags: assets, form, frontend

I have a frontend form to save an entry which includes a file upload input field:

```
<input type="file" name="fields[newsFile]">
```

The upload works fine, but is it also possible to set the title of the asset similar to the backend? Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[newsFile][title]" value="Asset Name">
```

Comment: Can you share some of the backend code you have to save the entry?

Comment: I basically just used the [entry form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form) from Craft with the input action "entries/saveEntry" and the [input file field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the answer is no; assets will initially just get titles based on their filenames until someone goes into the Control Panel and customizes them.

Comment: So a workaround solution would be to add a custom text field to the asset source and use that instead of title?

Comment: @carlcs Not sure what you mean, but there aren’t any workarounds (besides writing a plugin that hooks into asset saving).

Comment: I thought it is only a problem with the asset's title and other asset fields, like a custom plain text field "myTitle" would be possible. But I'm probably wrong.